# SQL, how to count days for how long a variable has been unchanged (time series)

Tags: sql

As an example I have 5 different stocks, where I only use end of day prices. The stocks do not change price often, maybe a couple of times per month.

I want a easy way to count the number of days the stocks have been unchanged, using the last available price.

One of the stocks may be "XYZ", the latest price is 103. Last time the price was changed was 23.10.2021, and the price went down from 104 to 103. How to automatically count the number of days the price has been at 103 in SQL?

Comment: just before the moment of updating the price do datediff https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: I do not update the price, the price is updated randomly by the market. In reality I have a many hundred stock prices I try to track, and I want to see for how long a price has been unchanged.

Comment: depends on the SQL server you are using you may use trigger for example like: `CREATE TRIGGER beforePriceUpdate BEFORE UPDATE ON stocks ...` which would be ideal solution